# How to start hazelcast client from console

Tags: hazelcast

How do I run a Hazelcast client from the console?

I have this config in `xml`:

```
<hazelcast-client xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config hazelcast-client-config-3.3.xsd"
       xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">



<network>
    <port auto-increment="true" port-count="100">5701</port>
    <outbound-ports>
        <!--
        Allowed port range when connecting to other nodes.
        0 or * means use system provided port.
        -->
        <ports>0</ports>
    </outbound-ports>
    <join>
        <multicast enabled="true">
            <multicast-group>224.2.2.3</multicast-group>
            <multicast-port>54327</multicast-port>
        </multicast>
    </join>
</network>

</hazelcast-client>
```

and I need a console like this when I run `run.sh` or `run.bat`, but I want it to be a client not a member.

Comment: have you tried writing/running a small application explicitly running as a client and connecting to a server (that came along with sample server)?  You can run the client from the console like any Java app or are you asking if Hazelcast has provided a sample client with their download package?

Comment: i already did it, like you said.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the clientConsole.bat given by Hazelcast to connect to any Hazelcast server and get a console for that. Using the console you can query any existing map or queue in your Hazelcast server.

I use hazelcast-3.8.1.
In the demo directory you can find clientConsole.bat/clientConsole.sh.
To connect to an existing server you need to provide the details in a "hazelcast-client.xml" file. Here is the content of "hazelcast-client.xml" file:

```
<hazelcast-client xmlns="http://www.hazelcast.com/schema/client-config">
    <group>
        <name>[GROUP_NAME]</name>
        <password>[GROUP_PASSWORD]</password>
    </group>
    <network>
        <cluster-members>
            <address>[HAZELCAST_SERVER_HOST_NAME_OR_IP]</address>
        </cluster-members>
    </network>
</hazelcast-client>
```

Above [HAZELCAST_SERVER_HOST_NAME_OR_IP] is the ip or hostname of hazelcast server which you want to connect and get client console.

[GROUP_NAME] and [GROUP_PASSWORD] should be same what is mentioned in "hazelcast.xml" file on Hazelcast server.